# What is operator"" that I saw in GoingNative2012

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-keyword

I recently watched GoingNative2012 about, of course, C++11.

In Bjarne Stroustrup section, I found out there was an interesting operator function, which was as belows.

```
constexpr Value<Second> operator""s(long double d)
{
     return Value<Second>(d);
}
```

Well, beside constexpr that looks like a new keyword in C++11,

I've never known "" is overload-able?

Is this one of the new features in C++ although I failed to test it using VS 2010?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you not listening to what he was saying when you watched it?

Comment: This code sample is incorrect in two ways: 1) whitespace is required between the "" and the suffix, and 2) user-defined suffixes should start with an underscore; suffixes not starting with an underscore are  reserved for future standardization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a new [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) core language feature: [user defined litterals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#User-defined_literals)

Comment: Take care though that as that article is on Wikipedia, it just _might_ not be entirely formally correct. (For instance, where it says “The characters "12.5" are a literal that is resolved by the compiler as a type double with the value of 12.5.”...)

Comment: Agreed that some details on Wikipedia may be slightly wrong, but it is a good and easy to understand summary of what the C++11 standard (nearly a thousand difficult pages to read) brings....

Comment: Here's a link to the section in the official C++11 FAQ: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#UD-literals

Comment: @MrLister: So, are the characters "12.5" not in fact a literal that is of type `double`? If not, then what are they?

Comment: @NicolBolas The characters "12.5" are a literal that is of type `const char[]`. You can tell by the fact that it says _characters._

Comment: @MrLister: So, when I type the characters `12.5` into my text editor of choice and press "compile", I get a `const char[]`? I'm pretty sure that's not true. I think you're getting hung up on the word "characters", which you think means the string literal `"12.5"` rather than what is *between* the quotes.

Comment: @NicolBolas Since you're starting to twist my words, I think this would be the best moment to stop this conversation.

Comment: @MrLister: I'm not twisting your words; that's what you said. You stated that the Wiki article is wrong because `The characters "12.5"` are a string literal, not a double. I'm saying that it depends on how you interpret the `"` marks. In English, quotes mean "exactly everything between these." In C++, quotes mean "string literal". So the article is correct, *depending* on how you look at it.